# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-preferences

Unable to resolve dependency for `':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.0.2.`

This is the information about android studio version :

> Android Studio 3.2.1 Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October
>   9, 2018 JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit
>   Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o Windows 10 10.0

This is gradle project :

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
  google()
jcenter()
 }
 dependencies {  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1' } }}
allprojects {repositories { jcenter() maven {  url "https://maven.google.com"}}}
task clean(type: Delete) { delete rootProject.buildDir}
```

and this is the Gradle APP

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android { compileSdkVersion 28   defaultConfig { 
 applicationId "com.example.alyossrgf.myapplication"
 minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 28
versionCode 1
 versionName "1.0"
 testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"}
 buildTypes {   release {  minifyEnabled false 
 proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' }}}
dependencies {
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'}
```

Can help to solve this Error

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.0.2.

Comment: Did you get the solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should make project clean (`Build -> Clean Project`) or clear Android Studio cache (`File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart`)?

Comment: this dont help  @stfbee